# Rasterio showing a blue (blank) image wrong

Tags: rasterio, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a raster in my Jupyter Notebook using rasterio. I began with two Landsat 8 images, which I processed in QGIS to calculate the NDVI. I want to plot the original images used for the calculation (band 4 and 5) along with the NDVI.

My NDVI plot however is a blue image, in QGIS and Windows however it does show correctly.

[image]

Comment: Please add the code as text